# What are the changes that will be included in the Metropolis/Byzantium network upgrade?

Tags: protocol, eip, metropolis

I see a number of EIPS are listed as [Accepted Changes](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/#accepted-eips-planned-for-adoption), but it is not clear if all the changes are for Metropolis/Byzantium, nor if all Metropolis/Byzantium changes are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the Meta EIP listing the changes included in the <s>hard fork</s> named Metropolis/Byzantium here: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/609

**Update:**

Metropolis has been split into two upgrades; Byzantium and Constantinople.

Metropolis/Byzantium is still describe in EIP 609 as above, with a nice ELI5 summary of changes from @avsa [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/702t95/eli5_byzantium_changes/).

Metropolis/Constantinople has almost no information I can find, except that [EIP96 has been deferred](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/685) until that upgrade.